# If a "The Phantom Knights" trap monster's effects are negated, is it turned back into a trap or no?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

"[The Phantom Knights](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/The_Phantom_Knights)" is an archetype that contains a number of Trap cards. They all have an effect that turns them into a Monster with an added effect that says they are not treated as Traps. For instance, [The Phantom Knights of Dark Gauntlets](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/The_Phantom_Knights_of_Dark_Gauntlets).

> Send 1 "Phantom Knights" Spell/Trap Card from your Deck to the Graveyard. When an opponent's monster declares a direct attack while you control no cards and this card is in your Graveyard: Special Summon this card in Defense Position as an Effect Monster (Warrior-Type/DARK/Level 4/ATK 300/DEF 600), but banish it when it leaves the field. (This card is NOT treated as a Trap Card.) If Summoned this way, this card gains 300 DEF for each "Phantom Knights" Spell/Trap Card in your Graveyard.

If their effects are negated, do they count as a Monster with negated effects or a Trap card?

Comment: Add a card description??

Comment: I rolled back the edit to this question as it took out information that was relevant to the question.

Comment: I've cleaned up your post and added a card description from one of the cards in that archetype. However, I'm not very familiar with this archetype, so if I misunderstood your question, please feel free to change what I've written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depend on the exact Text but most Phantom Knight Monster has the condition: "(This card is NOT treated as a Trap Card.)"

If the trap has this text, it will not return to be trap if the effect is negate, since it is not an effect but a condition. It is also uneffect by every card that is applied to Trap Cards (MST, Royal Decree, etc) and keeps being a Monster if it change to face-down position.

Without the condition, the answer from simples_mathematics appeal

For Ruling look at the wikia:
http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:The_Phantom_Knights_of_Shadow_Veil

Also note, that OCG-Ruling don't official apply in tcg tournaments, where the judge has the last word, but still should be used as navigation points